The integration of $\frac1{[(1-x^2)^{1/4}+\sqrt x]^9 (1-x^2)^{1/4}}$
How to solve the following integral?
$$
{\tt I} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm d}x}
{\left[\left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{1/4} + \sqrt{x}\right]^{9}
\left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{1/4}}
$$
My attempt: I substituted x = $\cos\theta$,
then it reduces to $$
{\tt I} = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{{\rm (\sqrt{\sin\theta})}{\rm d}\theta}
{\left[(\sqrt{\sin\theta}) + (\sqrt{\cos\theta})\right]^{9}}
$$ after that on applying King's rule and adding the two integrals we get
$$
{\tt I} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{{\rm d}\theta}
{\left(\cos^4\theta\right) \left[1 + (\sqrt{\tan\theta})\right]^{8}}
$$ Now I substituted $t = (1+\sqrt{\tan\theta})$, then I got $$
{\tt I} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm 
((t-1)^5 + (t-1)) d}{\rm t}}
{t^{8}}
$$ Further expanding the numerator and integrating individual terms we get the answer ${\tt I} = \frac{1}{21}$.
This method is tedious and lengthy due to the big numerator. What would be a better approach(shorter) to this question?

With Mathematica: $I=\frac{1}{21}$

Welcome to MSE! Trigonometric substitution works, at least in carving out a path to a simpler integral. Why don't you try some things and edit your post to include your attempt?

I had the same solution in mind, up to the last substitution where I used $u=\sqrt{\tan\theta}$, followed by $u=\dfrac{1-v}{1+v}$:
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \frac12 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{\sec^4\theta}{\left(1+\sqrt{\tan \theta}\right)^8} \, d\theta \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{u \left(1+u^4\right)}{(1+u)^8} \, du \\
&= \frac1{64} \int_{-1}^1 \left(1+5v^2-5v^4-v^6\right) \, dv
\end{align*}$$

what is the logic behind your substitution of u = (1-v)/(1+v)?

@Chetan See When to use $y=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ ...
